# Error: Class 'App\Model\Entity\DefaultPasswordHasher' not found

Tags: cakephp-3.0

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * User Entity.
 */
class User extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     * Note that '*' is set to true, which allows all unspecified fields to be
     * mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($value)
    {
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        return $hasher->hash($value);
    }
}
```

Here is my code in user.php.
I am hashing the password and got this one error

> **Error**: Class 'App\Model\Entity\DefaultPasswordHasher' not found  File
>   C:\xamp\htdocs\bookmarker\src\Model\Entity\User.php  Line: 27

Answer (score 24):

I was missing the following line:

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
```

This was the reason why I got the error.

Comment: I'm getting `Error: syntax error, unexpected '?' ` on that line. Any clue?

Comment: @JackTheKnife check your syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you using `cakephp version 4.0` and
already included these two for password hashing in your php file:

```
use Authentication\PasswordHasher\DefaultPasswordHasher;


{
    $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
    return $hasher->hash($password);
}
```

as mention in official [`cakephp 4.0 documentation`](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html)

And still get an error like this:

```
Undefined type 'Authentication\PasswordHasher\DefaultPasswordHasher'. 
intelephense(1009) [50,23]
```

.

Then instead of using:

```
 use Authentication\PasswordHasher\DefaultPasswordHasher;
   
 $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
```

use this:

```
 use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher as AuthDefaultPasswordHasher;

 $hasher = new AuthDefaultPasswordHasher();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This:

```
protected function _setPassword($value) {
    return sha1($value);
}
```

Comment: Although you probably aren't dealing with high security, it's worth noting that sha1 is now considered to be compromised (e.g. https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/02/23/google_first_sha1_collision/)